# two functions from different packages not working together

Tags: r, math, statistics

So I am doing work on ruin probability. I am performing monte-carlo simulations through R. The package that works perfectly for this is **'ruin'**. You simply specify inputs for different ruin models. I am trying to simulate a SparreAndersen model where there are two random variable generators from different distributions. Typical distributions such as exponential or gamma work fine, using rgamma or rexp.

The problem that I am having is that I require a **mixed exponential function** as one of the r.v. generators. I found a great package that achieves this, called **'gendist'** where I use the rmixt function to generate r.v.s from a mixed exponential function.

Running rmixt with all parameters works fine, giving a correct and accurate numerical output.
Running rexp with all parameters works fine, giving a correct and accurate numerical output.
Running a SparreAndersen() function works fine when using any function that is NOT the rmixt function.

**The problem: SparreAndersen does not like to use rmixt from 'gendist' package as a r.v. generator**

[When I try to run this function, I get this as an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuVRl.png)

I have no idea why this isn't working???
See my entire code below:

```
library(ruin)
library(gendist)

rmixt(1, phi=1, spec1="exp", arg1=list(rate=3), spec2="exp",
      arg2=list(rate=7) )

rexp(1, rate=1)

modelSA <- SparreAndersen(initial_capital = 1,
                          premium_rate = 5,
                          claim_interarrival_generator = rmixt,
                          claim_interarrival_parameters = list(1, phi=1, spec1="exp", arg1=list(rate=3), spec2="exp", arg2=list(rate=7)),
                          claim_size_generator = rexp,
                          claim_size_parameters = list(rate=1))
```

**edit: I have found a working solution, not involving the 'gendist' package. Let me know if this is the best way to go about doing this.**

My new working code:

```
# Function which generates multiple exponential
rmixedexp <- function(...) {
  choice <- c(...)
  return(rexp(n=1, sample(choice, 1, replace=TRUE)))
}

modelSA <- SparreAndersen(initial_capital = 5,
                         premium_rate = 5,
                         claim_interarrival_generator = rmixedexp,
                         claim_interarrival_parameters = list(1, 3, 7),
                         claim_size_generator = rexp,
                         claim_size_parameters = list(rate=1))
```

I had to make my own function which takes any number of parameters, for example, 2. Each parameter is the **rate** of the exponential, chosen randomly (probability half).

Comment: Try adding `list(n=1,...` i.e. name `n=1` in `claim_interarrival_parameters` or in fact omit the `n=1`

Comment: You can help others help you by pasting the exact error message into your problem statement, instead of asking them to look at an image on a different page.

Comment: I have achieved success in making my own function. If you have any recommendations on how this can be improved (since I am running it 1000s of times) it would be highly appreciated.